# Citing TikZ and other packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, bibtex, bibliographies, packages, citing

In some areas of maths, it is advised to cite mathematical and drawing software you use to make your computations and drawings. Since I draw in TikZ, I would like to know how officially cite the package in my article. I use BibTeX, in this case with `amsalpha` style, as in MWE below.

*(Related to [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-properly-cite-tex-se-for-its-help-in-typesetting) which, however, treats citing this site rather than packages themselves.)*

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}

@misc{dummy,
TITLE = {Dummy Software},
AUTHOR = {John Doe},
YEAR = {2013},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

I want to cite \cite{dummy}, and I want to cite \cite{tikz} as well.

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{bibtest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

I would (and I do) cite it as a `@manual`:

```
@manual{tantau:2013a,
   author    = {Till Tantau},
   title     = {The TikZ and PGF Packages},
   subtitle  = {Manual for version 3.0.0},
   url       = {http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/},
   date      = {2013-12-20},
}
```

The same goes for other packages.

Answer (score 3):

For software it would be relevant to include the  information about the version/release of the software. With Bibtex this information can be stored in the `howpublished` field.

```
@misc{dummy,
TITLE = {Dummy Software},
AUTHOR = {John Doe},
YEAR = {2013},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Version 0.1},
}
```

Biblatex offers the entry type `software` (though unsupported, i.e., standard style will treat it as `misc`), has the field `version`.

```
@software{dummy,
title = {Dummy Software},
author = {John Doe},
year = {2013},
version = {0.1},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for the TikZ `graphdrawing` library, I would recommend citing [the following formally archived peer-reviewed article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-36763-2_46).

```
@inproceedings{Tan12,
    author = {Tantau, Till},
    title = {Graph Drawing in {TikZ}},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 20th International Conference on Graph Drawing},
    series = {GD'12},
    year = {2013},
    isbn = {978-3-642-36762-5},
    location = {Redmond, WA},
    pages = {517--528},
    numpages = {12},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-36763-2_46},
    publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
    address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
}
```

This will also help the package's author get appropriate recognition in bibliometric studies.

Comment: In that article the content is  only related to one library which is `graphdrawing`. The manual is the one that should be cited.